# How to retrieve the rows in a table that has a value that appears NOT the most times?

Tags: mysql, apache

I have two tables.

A `customers` table and an `orders` table.

```
customers:                          orders:
customer_id      customer_name      orders_id   customer_id
1111             Charles            1020        1111
2222             Bertram            1021        1111
3333             Barbare            1022        2222
                                    1023        3333
```

I want the output to be:

```
customer_name
Bertram
Barbara
```

I want to retrieve only the order from `Bertram` and `Barbara` because they have not placed an order the highest numbers of times.

The problem here is the subquery. I know how the count the numbers of times a customer has placed an order, but I am having real difficulties selecting the `customer_id` that occurs the fewest times.

Using mySQL and Apache

Comment: please specify db engine, e.g. sql server, oracle, postgresql?

Comment: Fewest times is relative. Fewest compared to what? If one customer has 100 orders, another has 40, another has 30 and another has 10, they all have fewer than the maximum number of orders (which is 100), but how many would you need to select of them?! Do you need the customers having the minimum number of orders?!

Comment: Do you want to fetch exactly one column (`customer_name`)? It's important to know that if we have to group records.

Comment: Which SQL? Each dbms has their own way of doing things.  Please tag properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, you may be finding customers with just 1 order, with that you may use the following query

```
SELECT customer_name
  FROM customer c
  JOIN orders o
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 GROUP BY customer_name
HAVING COUNT(orders_id) = 1
```

Result

```
customer_name
Bertram
Barbara
```

Comment: as I said, based on the sample data, OP may change the condition based on his intended number of count

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify the database you are using I assume you are stuck with standard SQL (analytic functions are not available). Then you can rely on the ALL operator:

```
WITH count_table AS (SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS num_of_orders
                     FROM your_table
                     GROUP BY customer_id)
SELECT *
FROM count_table
WHERE num_of_orders <= ALL(SELECT num_of_orders FROM count_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `rank()` for this purpose:

```
select oc.*
from (select o.customer_id, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) asc) as seqnum
      from orders o
      group by o.customer_id
     ) oc
where seqnum = 1;
```

This does not return the name.  But getting the name is a simple join.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it!

```
    SELECT c.customer_id COUNT(o.order_id) "Orders"
    FROM orders o 
    INNER JOIN customers c 
    ON (o.customer_id = c.customer_id)
    GROUP BY o.customer_id
    HAVING Orders < ANY 
                        (SELECT COUNT(ord.customer_id)
                         FROM orders ord
                         GROUP BY ord.customer_id)
```